# Turning functions into a class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop

Hi Im trying to get my code to now come together in a class but am at this point a bit lost. Any pointers would be appreciated!

The current functions and queries are for a IMDB data base challenge. The queries gather data from a csv file with IMDB movies. Ive created a connection to the table and functions below.

```
import argparse
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import pandas as pd


# Create Database
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


# Create table
def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    """ create a table from the create_table_sql statement
    :param conn: Connection object
    :param create_table_sql: a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:
    """
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)


# Top 10 movies based on IMDB rating
def select_top10_movies(conn, table):
    """
        parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
        return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT Series_Title, Imdb_Rating FROM {table} GROUP BY Imdb_Rating "
                f"order by Imdb_Rating DESC LIMIT 10")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Top 10 lead actors (Star1 field) based on their movies average IMDB rating
def select_top10_leadactors(conn, table):
    """
        parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
        return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT Star1, AVG(Imdb_rating) AS avg_imdb FROM {table} GROUP by Star1 ORDER BY avg_imdb "
                f"DESC LIMIT 10")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Given a user input value of a year (e.g. 1990) return all the movies from that year, sorted by IMDB rating
def select_year_imdb(conn, table):
    """
    parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
    return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT Series_Title, IMDB_Rating FROM {table} WHERE Released_Year like '%1990%' ORDER BY "
                f"IMDB_rating DESC")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Given a user input value of a year (e.g. 2019) determine the longest running movie of the year and return it,
# along with its runtime in hours.
def select_longest_movie(conn, table):
    """
    parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
    return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT Series_Title, Runtime FROM {table} WHERE Released_Year like '%2019%' ORDER BY "
                f"Runtime DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Determine the year that had the highest grossing movies and return it, along with the average gross of movies that
# year.
def select_highest_grossing_movie(conn, table):
    """
    parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
    return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT Released_Year, AVG(Gross) FROM {table} GROUP BY Released_Year ORDER BY AVG(Gross) "
                f"DESC LIMIT 1")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


# Given a user input of part of a movie name (e.g. lord of the rings) return all matching movies and their IMDB rating
def find_movie(conn, table):
    """
    parameter: Query all rows in the task table.
    return: The connection object.
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT Series_Title, IMDB_Rating FROM {table} WHERE Series_Title like '%lord of the "
                f"rings%' ORDER BY "
                f"IMDB_Rating DESC")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


def main():
    # Read in command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--database', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--table', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--query', type=str, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=bool, required=False, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--movie', type=str, required=False, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--year', type=str, required=False, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--min', type=int, required=False, default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    database = args.database

    # Create database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)

    # 2 - 3: CSV import into database
    if args.seed:
        users = pd.read_csv('imdb_top_1000.csv')
        users.to_sql(args.table, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    else:
        pass

    # 4 - Queries
    query = args.query

    if query == "top_10_movies":
        print("Top 10 movies based on IMDB rating:")
        select_top10_movies(conn, args.table)
    elif query == "top_10_actors":
        print("Top 10 lead actors based on their movies average IMDB rating:")
        select_top10_leadactors(conn, args.table)
    elif query == "year":
        if args.movie is None:
            print("Error: Sorry buddy I need a --movie input please")
        select_year_imdb(conn, args.table)
    elif query == "longest_movie":
        if args.movie is None:
            print("Error: Sorry buddy I need a --movie input please")
        select_longest_movie(conn, args.table)
    elif query == "gross_year":
        print("The highest grossing movies for the year: ")
        select_highest_grossing_movie(conn, args.table)
    elif query == "find_movie":
        if args.movie is None:
            print("Error: Sorry buddy I need a --movie input please")
        print("Matching movies and their IMDB rating")
        find_movie(conn, args.table)

    else:
        print("Error: Unknown query")
    exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Here is a pointer: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.